# Add Legend to Donut Chart - jqPlot

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jqplot, donut-chart

OK, this should be relatively simple :

[image]

- I'm adding a donut chart, which does work
- However, the 'legend' (like `Head (+)` along with the corresponding colour) does NOT show up.

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var s1 = [['Head (+)',<?php echo $headScore; ?>], ['Head (-)',<?php echo 6-$headScore; ?>]];
  var s2 = [['Body (+)',<?php echo $totalScore-$headScore; ?>], ['Body (-)',<?php echo 7-$totalScore+$headScore; ?>]];

  var plot3 = $.jqplot('linkchart', [s1,s2], {
      title:"Score Profile",
    seriesDefaults: {
      // make this a donut chart.
      renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
      rendererOptions:{
        // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
        sliceMargin: 3,
        // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
        startAngle: -90,
        showDataLabels: false
      },
      legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    }
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kameleon,

It looks like you have done a silly mistake. : )

First end the seriesDefaults property and then define the legend.

You have placed the legend inside the seriesDefaults.

```
var plot3 = $.jqplot('linkchart', [s1,s2], {
    title:"Score Profile",
        seriesDefaults: {
            // make this a donut chart.
            renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
            rendererOptions:{
                // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
                sliceMargin: 3,
                // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
                startAngle: -90,
                showDataLabels: false
            } // Not here...
        },
        //Place the legend here....
        legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    });
});
```

I have not tested it. But I think it should work.

Thank you.

Comment: OMG! Anish, Thank you so much! This was a really silly one, but... one I couldn't actually spot myself! :-)